# Derivation of two matrices using lcm and gcd

Tags: matrices

I need to form two $6 \times 6$ matrices where (i) each element $b_{i,j}$ is the lcm of $i$ and $j$ (ii) individual element $c_{i,j}$ is the gcd of $i$ and $j$.

Comment: How can it be both the lcm and the gcd?  Do you want two matrices?

Comment: @  saulspatz. Yes, it should have both!

Comment: @Omojola both can't be possible, e.g. gcd(3,1)=1 and lcm(3,1)=3

Comment: @ gimusi. Hmm... I think you are correct! Alright, let me edit my question and see if your answer would suit it.

Comment: @ gimusi. Thanks for pointing out the error! I was about correcting it when you noticed.

Comment: @ gimusi. Thank you very much! I have applied your formula and it worked!

Comment: @Omojola I'm very happy for that. You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that for

- row 1: $\gcd(1,j)=1 \quad \text{lcm}(1,j)=j$
- column 1: $\gcd(i,1)=1 \quad \text{lcm}(i,1)=i$
- use the definition for others entries
- you can also use the following [gcd-lcm formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Reduction_by_the_greatest_common_divisor)

Comment: @ gimusi. I have just edited my question.